# Simple Reliable Fade Page Transition in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, fadein, transition, fadeout

I am working on a website and I have one last thing to do. I am trying to create a page transition. The transition needs to be a fade out and fade into the next page. I tried alot of scripts and can't get them to work. I tried a few different plugins and one of the plugins works ok but my slideshow isn't showing up. Is there any easy CSS code or JS code for this? I thought about maybe writing a transition CSS code for a DIV, but I don't know how to go about it. Any easy suggestions?

html code:

```
 <body>
  <div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a><li>
    <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="FADE">
   <!----CONTENT THAT NEEDS TO FADE UPON CLICKING ABOUT US PAGE--->
 </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can just use `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`

**For CSS:**

It is hard to say exactly how it would fit into your code, but I would suggest just creating a `.fade` div that covers the entire page that you can add and remove dynamically to create the transition.

```
.fade{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100000;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.fade.hidden {
    opacity:0;
    z-index:0;
    width:0;
}
```

Then you can simply toggle the ".hidden" class to show the transition. This should work, but might not fit in with what you had in mind.

Comment: How would you write the JS?

Comment: Could something like this work? 

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".fade").fadeIn(3000);
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    link = this.href;
    $("#fade").fadeOut(3000, function(){
        window.location = link;
    });
});</script>

Comment: Hard to give you any specific help without actually knowing how you are moving from page to page. Are you just using a normal link, but wanting the fade to happen to make it seem like you aren't, or are you actually loading a new page?